# how to add previous List Data in to New List in android

Tags: java, android

```
final ReviewItem reviewItem = (ReviewItem) responseBody;
final List reviewList = new ArrayList();//

ReviewHeaderItem header = new ReviewHeaderItem();
header.setTotalRatng(reviewItem.getAvg_rating());
header.setTotalReviews(reviewItem.getNum_reviews());
reviewList.add(header);
List<Reviews> lisOfReviews = reviewItem.getReviews();

List newReviewList=new ArrayList();


if (lisOfReviews.size() < 10) {
  reviewList.addAll(lisOfReviews);
  newReviewList.addAll(reviewList);

  } else {
    reviewList.addAll(lisOfReviews);

    newReviewList.addAll(reviewList);

    reviewList.add("");


  }

  configureList(reviewList);

  final ReviewItem reviewItem = (ReviewItem) responseBody;
```

i m getting response on each button click and i store it in List now  what i want suppose if in first time response i get 10 record then again i have hit and i get another 10 record then i want to add it in previous list and dynmically we have to add it please suggest me how to implment it.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? `arrlist.addAll(arrlist2);` isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I used handler so that 5 seconds delay can be made and In your case, you have to make server call there

```
final List<String> reviewList = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> response1 = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> response2 = new ArrayList<>();
     response1.add("First");response1.add("Second");response1.add("Third");
            response2.add("Four");response2.add("Five");response2.add("Six");

            for (int i = 0; i < response1.size(); i++) {
                reviewList.add(response1.get(i));
            }
            Handler handler= new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response2.size(); i++) {
                        reviewList.add(response2.get(i));
                    }

                }
            },500);

            Handler handler2= new Handler();
            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reviewList.size(); i++) {
                        Log.v("@@@WWe"," "+reviewList.get(i));
                    }

                }
            },500);
```